# To use doParallel in R

Tags: r

In R I can run this succesfully but it takes some time for large m.

```
m=10
u=c()
for(i in 1:m){
newdata <- subset(pgz, pgz$user_id==i)
    if(dim(newdata)[1] > 0) {
    u[i] <- i
    } else{u[i] <-0}
}
```

Now I want to use library(doParallel)
So I type this

```
u=c()
foreach(i in 1:m){

%do%

newdata <- subset(pgz, pgz$user_id==i)
    if(dim(newdata)[1] > 0) {
    u[i] <- i
    } else{u[i] <-0}
}
```

But R does not accept this. How should one write this so it can run ?

Comment: *R does not accept this*. Why not? What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be specifying the number of cores to use based on the code above and the foreach loop needs to be written a bit differently.

```
library(doParallel)

m = 10
u=c()
registerDoParallel(cores=2)

foreach(i= 1:m) %dopar%{
    newdata <- subset(pgz, pgz$user_id==i)
  if(dim(newdata)[1] > 0) {
    u[i] <- i
  } 
  else{u[i] <-0}
}
```